# Append href links into a dataframe list, getting all required info, but only links from last page appears

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

Using Beautiful Soup and pandas, I am trying to append all the links on a site into a list with the following code. I am able to **scrape** all pages with relevant information in the table. The code seems work to me somehow. But the small problem occurs is that just only links in the last page appears. The output is not what I expected. In the end, I'd like to append a list containing all 40 links (next to the required info) in 2 pages. I try **scraping** 2 pages first although there are 618 pages in total. Do you have any advice how to adjust the code so that each link is appended into the table?  Many thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

hdr={'User-Agent':'Chrome/84.0.4147.135'}

dfs=[]

for page_number in range(2):
    http= "http://example.com/&Page={}".format(page_number+1)

    print('Downloading page %s...' % http)
    url= requests.get(http,headers=hdr)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')
    df_list= pd.read_html(url.text)
    df = pd.concat(df_list)
    dfs.append(df)

links = []
for tr in table.findAll("tr"):
    trs = tr.findAll("td")
    for each in trs:
        try:
            link = each.find('a')['href']
            links.append(link)
        except:
            pass

df['Link'] = links

final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
final_df.to_csv('myfile.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's with your logic. You only add the links column to the last df since it's outside your loop. Get the links within the page loop, then add that to `df`, then you can append the df to your `dfs` list:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

hdr={'User-Agent':'Chrome/84.0.4147.135'}

dfs=[]

for page_number in range(2):
    http= "http://example.com/&Page={}".format(page_number+1)

    print('Downloading page %s...' % http)
    url= requests.get(http,headers=hdr)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')
    df_list= pd.read_html(url.text)
    df = pd.concat(df_list)
    

    links = []
    for tr in table.findAll("tr"):
        trs = tr.findAll("td")
        for each in trs:
            try:
                link = each.find('a')['href']
                links.append(link)
            except:
                pass
    
    df['Link'] = links
    dfs.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
final_df.to_csv('myfile.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: It works wonderfully! That’s exactly what I was looking for! Much appreciated your help!